# Jar file does not (Image loading related issue)

Tags: java, image, netbeans, jar

I am working on a loading screen for a school project. In Netbeans the code runs fine, but when I create an executable jar the .jar file does not execute.

I think the issue is related to the background image Loading since when I remove this chuck of code from my project. The .jar execute but when I add it to load the backgound image the .jar file does not execute. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
private void loadBackground(){
     try {
        backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(
               LoadingScreen.class.getResource("../resources/linen.png"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoadingScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   Background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(backgroundImage));
}
```

Comment: Start the jar from the command line using `java -jar yourApp.jar` and see if any exception gets fired. If you see exceptions, paste them here

Comment: Try without "../"  and make sure that your image is present in your jar in the directory resources.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved by removing the ".." from the background image path.   LoadingScreen.class.getResource("/resources/linen.png"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`Class#getResource(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of
>   the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
>
> Otherwise,
>   the absolute name is of the following form: modified_package_name/name
>   Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object
>   with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

The `../` makes no sense because it would resolve to a resource name

```
com/yourclasspackage/../resources/linen.png
```

I recommend you always use absolute paths in the resource path, ie. paths starting with `/`. In your case,

```
LoadingScreen.class.getResource("/resources/linen.png"));
```

assuming `/resources/linen.png` is at the root of the classpath.